# Trying to install LTspice

Tags: wine, ubuntu-studio

Pretty new to linux and can't tell if Wine is installed more or less working.

I am running Ubuntu Studio 18.04. I've "installed" Wine at least 3 different ways with different commands.

The best result I get when running `sudo wine LTspiceXVII.exe` is the messafe `wine: /home/lucas/.wine is not owned by you`.

I also have nothing in the right click menu for Wine, and the only application I have is "run wine", it does nothing.

Comment: Don't run wine with `sudo` to avoid ownership problems. To fix the ownership, run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/lucas/.wine`, then try to install again, ...and no `sudo`.

Comment: first command ran perfectly fine. Is that to remove any current installation? Trying to redownload without sudo did not work. Gives the "mus run as root" error. https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu I am downloading from here if that helps.                           Re read your response. I misread it. Anyway, it if giving me an error of not finding the file. The executable is in my downloads.

Comment: Installing wine from anywhere except the official Ubuntu repository isn't supported, so there's that. Additionally, not everything that runs on Windows can run in wine, so chances are LTSplce simply will not work. You can't expect Ubuntu (or any Linux distribution) to run like Windows. Not that it runs worse, it's just different.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing from the official Ubuntu repository. I have got LTspice working

[LTspice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3WoC.png)

Here's how I did it.

Using the apt repository. The –install-recommends option will install all the recommended packages by winehq stable versions on your Ubuntu system.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install wine-stable
```

or

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Once wine is installed, check the version using

```
wine --version
```

If the above doesn't work, try the official wine installation at https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Once wine is installed, download the windows executable file at https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html.

```
wine LTspiceXVII.exe
```

or

Click on LTspiceIv.exe and open it with wine. Wine will install the program and happy simulating!

Comment: Any idea how to automatically accept the EULA, and avoid the pop up window for unattended, scripted installation?

Comment: @poleguy ooh I am not sure about it :) sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess around with wine directly, I can verify that it runs on PlayOnLinux as well. Just download the windows binary and install it as a new application.